# how can you generate a random number in Autohotkey?

Tags: autohotkey

I have this little script in autohotkey and I need both sleep number to be random, first from 700 to 900 and the second from 1800 to 2200. Anyone knows how to do it? Thanks! This is the script:

```
F3::SetTimer, aLoop, % (on:=!on) ? "50" : "Off"

aLoop:
Click down
Sleep, 1400
Click u
Sleep 2000
return
```

Comment: While Autohotkey might be programmed in C++, the scripts it uses (and the one you show) isn't themselves in C++. You have to read the Autohotkey documentation to find out how to create and use random numbers in scripts.

Comment: This does not look like C++...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is an AHK question, not a C++ question.

Use the [Random](https://www.autohotkey.com/docs/commands/Random.htm) function:

> Syntax: `Random, OutputVar , Min, Max`

For example:

```
Random var, 100, 200
```

This will generate a random number from 100 to 200 and store the result in the variable "var"

---

Solution for your case:

```
F3::SetTimer, aLoop, % (on:=!on) ? "50" : "Off"

aLoop:
Click down
Random rand, 700, 900
Sleep, rand
Click u
Random rand, 1800, 2200
Sleep, rand
return
```